# Android and Google Play: several applications with the same name?

Tags: android, branding, google-play

I have a problem publishing my apps on the Google Play that never happened to me before. Basically, I have 3 applications based on the same code. Each of them has a different default language (English, Spanish and French) but supports all languages (more than 10).

When I tried to publish an updated version of my English app, the Google Play display an error saying that the English name of this app is already taken by the Spanish and French apps. Should I remove some of the supported languages in my applications?

I must keep the 3 apps because I have created 3 different brands, so one app for each brand.

Comment: Still did not solve this issue?..

Comment: Still having this issue. Do you face the same problem?

Comment: No I'm not, but I'm very curious about how to handle this specific case...

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you use similar package names?

Two different applications **cannot have the same package name** on the Market, nor should be allowed on your device.

Comment: I don't use the same package names. The package names I use are: com.englishname.android and com.spanishname.android and com.frenchname.android.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the **version number** of your application before uploading the update?

Comment: yes I did, otherwise an error would have occurred while uploading the APK.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem when there was an app with the same name, which I had previously published.
I un-published the original app, which was free, and then uploaded the new app and the problem got resolved.

However now I'm about to create a new app, there is another app by some other developer with the same name. I don't get any error when I try to create an app with the same name but I'm wondering whether I should do that.